# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - JS Error, when php put's a single qutoe or apostrophe in function parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Alright I am using AJAX to generate a list of potential customer matches from a WebService.  Everything is working except for this part in my pHp ...

```
$html = "<h3> Search Results: ";

        if(!is_array($searchResults))
        {
            $html .= $searchResults . "</h3>";
        }
        else{
            $html .= "</h3><ul>";
            foreach($searchResults as $result)
            {
                $html .= '<li> <a href="#" onclick="selectCustomer('. "'" . htmlentities((string)$result->entityId, ENT_QUOTES) . "'" . ')">' . $result->entityId . "</a></li>";
            }
            $html .= "</ul>";
        }

        echo $html;
```

Here is my select JavaScript selectCustomer function:

```
    <script>
function selectCustomer(selectedCustomer){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "<?php echo JURI::base() . "index.php?option=com_sample&view=place_order&task=getCustomer&customerName=";?>" + encodeURIComponent(selectedCustomer),
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#CustomerInfo').html('<div class="loading"><img src="<?php echo JURI::base() . "components/com_joomsuite/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif"?>" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#CustomerInfo').html(data);
                    $('#customerEmail').val($('#customerEmailAJAX').html());
                    $('#customerName').val($('#customerNameAJAX').html());
                },
                error:function(){
                    $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

You may have noticed a little pHp in my JS using Joomla :P... this function is used successfully in 2 other situations.  It only fails when it is called from the onclick that gets displayed via AJAX.

Chrome keeps throwing the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" but no line #.  I'm assuming that it has something to do with the onclick call.

I went into chrome's inspect element and found this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="selectCustomer('13064 Moto's Burger Palace')">13064 Moto's Burger Palace</a>
```

So here is the apparent problem right?  Its the same old "You put your apostrophe by my single quote" argument from when you were a kid.  But shouldn't the htmlentities() function be preventing this... well no because the apostrophe gets rendered by chrome (the browser).

So my question is (finally) what can I change in my php function that will allow the onclick to run my selectCustomer function and correctly pass a string that may or may not contain an apostrophe...

I would prefer to change this line (but am willing to accept other possibilities):

```
$html .= '<li> <a href="#" onclick="selectCustomer('. "'" . htmlentities((string)$result->entityId, ENT_QUOTES) . "'" . ')">' . $result->entityId . "</a></li>";
```

Comment: What does the PHP-generated javascript look like?

Comment: `addslashes()` to the php value so that strings with quotes are escape before the JS is called

Comment: @PRPGFerret quotes are not the only problem, newlines and paragraph separators also break it... it's just not worth it at all when it's easily avoidable

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it a lot by not using onclick attributes.

```
<a href="#" data-customer="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result->entityId); ?>">13064 Moto's Burger Palace</a>
```

That way you only have to escape for html, not for HTML *and* Javascript, which is just insane.

Then just have simple static code like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-customer]", function(){
    selectCustomer($(this).attr("data-customer"));
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... no dice on this one.  Tried and failed... didn't even call the function.  Also what's wrong with using onclick?  How is it simpler to add a jQuery function to do what onclick does?  I don't think one works because I'll displaying the list via AJAX which means the [data-customer] isn't displayed until after the page is already loaded.

Comment: @Cleanshooter like I said, you don't have to escape for both HTML and Javascript with this, that's what's simpler about it. One could also make arguments for maintainability but that should not be necessary here.

Comment: @Cleanshooter I have edited the code to use event delegation so it works on elements that have not been created when the listener is bound.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() wasn't really doing anything productive (by the looks of it) anyway :(... But this looks like it would work now... I've never used event delegation in jQuery interesting :)

Comment: @Cleanshooter I don't know what that means :) You can also use htmlentities if you think that works better for you.

Comment: If you look at what was rendered by the browser after it went through htmlspecialchars ( I also tried htmlentities) it still looked like "<a href="#" onclick="selectCustomer('13064 Moto's Burger Palace')">13064 Moto's Burger Palace</a>"  when the source was viewed in Chrome.  That's what I ment when I said it wasn't being productive... I was expecting to get '13064 Moto&#39;s Burger Palace' or something...

Comment: @Cleanshooter If you want single quotes escaped you need to pass `ENT_QUOTES`. But this is unnecessary for a data attribute delimited by double quotes.... And if you're insisting on using onclick you still need to escape *for* Javascript *as well as* HTML (so `&#39;` doesn't help there because it's *only* escaping for HTML). I am only using what's necessary in the data case.

Answer (score 0):

@PRPGFerret nailed it.  I found another possibility while I was searching as well:

**Solution 1:**

```
$html .= '<li> <a href="#" onclick="selectCustomer('. "'" . addslashes($result->entityId) . "'" . ')">' . $result->entityId . "</a></li>";
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$html .= '<li> <a href="#" onclick="selectCustomer(this.id)" id="' . $result->entityId . '">' . $result->entityId . "</a></li>";
```

Comment: But now you are not encoding for html, `\"` will break out of the attribute and mess it. For HTML you need `&quot;`...

Comment: As you pointed out earlier I was escaping things twice once on the pHp side and again in the javascript function.  The encodeURIComponent() should escape all the characters that need to be.

Comment: Well I hope you test with input that contains newlines, double quotes and single quotes